# oracle LISTAGG grouping multiple row results into one row not working. ORA-00909

Tags: sql, oracle, aggregate

I saw a post here to use LISTAGG to group multiple rows into one row under 1 column, I looked at the post example and oracle website but I can't get the query to work.

in sql developer, the error is ORA-00909: invalid number of arguments

I have the following query

```
select d.id, d.name, d.date_sale, d.address, d.city, d.state, d.zipcode, d.description, d.explanation, d.received_date, 
       listagg(dd.my_id, dd.customer_name, dd.category, dd.transaction_date, ';' 
       ) within group (order by dd.transaction_date)
from table1 d
left join table2 dd on d.id = dd.my_id
where d.id =1 and d.isActive =1
```

any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Concatenate the values together and add a `group by`:

```
select d.id, d.name, d.date_sale, d.address, 
       listagg(dd.my_id || dd.customer_name || dd.category, dd.transaction_date, ';' 
              ) within group (order by dd.transaction_date)
from table1 d left join
     table2 dd
     on d.id = dd.my_id
where d.id =1 and d.isActive = 1
group by d.id, d.name, d.date_sale, d.address;
```

Comment: HI Gordon, I got it work by your example, but I have roughly 40 fields under my first select, Do I add all 40 in the 'Group By'? Thanks

Comment: @user1250264 . . . Either that or use a subquery.  That would be a different question, though.